# Read lines reactively with Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, http, streaming, webclient

TLDR: how can I process GET response line-by-line by using Spring WebClient (reactive one)?

Details:

- Remote server returns response with size up to 20 Gb
- My service parses lines separately (each line is encoded into UTF8) and streams the result (99% of lines are skipped)
- I don't want to load whole response into the memory, e.g. I'd like to parse server update line-by-line.

Unfortunately I did not find any solutions to convert `Flux<ByteBuffer>` to `Flux<String>` (by splitting at the end of line).

**Question:** are there any embedded converters/decoders to do this?

Possible solution:

- Create temporary buffer (which is empty initially)
- For each input buffer:

  - Prepend temporary buffer to the new, re-create temporary buffer.
  - Try read single line from this buffer (e.g. read until end of line):
  - If there are bytes left - return this string and repeat line reading
  - If buffer is finished (e.g. no line separators there): just copy these bytes to the temporary buffer.
- After the last buffer: read temporary buffer until end.

Also: you could not just convert input buffer to string, because some utf8 characters can start at the buffer N and continue at the buffer N+1.

Comment: Hi! Could you find solution for your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Please see my answer below. I just use synchronous client for this instead. I tried working with ktor client, however it went to infinite loop for line-by-line reading mode.

Answer (score 1):

I Haven't found an embedded one, I'm using something like the code below. I'm assuming you are using single char `\n` line endings and that `\n` is always encoded as a single byte char in any encoding this class sees, e.g. UTF16 would not be supported.

```java
Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<String>>>  = webclient
                .post()
                .uri(...)
                .contentType(...)
                .bodyValue(...)
                .retrieve()
                .toEntityFlux(new LineBodyExtractor());
```

```java
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.util.MimeType;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractor;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import static java.util.Optional.of;


/**
 * Only supports single char separators and charsets
 **/
public class LineBodyExtractor implements BodyExtractor<Flux<String>, ClientHttpResponse> {
    private static final String SEPARATOR_CHAR = "\n";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Flux<String> extract(ClientHttpResponse inputMessage, @NonNull Context ignored) {
        var charSet = of(inputMessage.getHeaders())
                .map(HttpHeaders::getContentType)
                .map(MimeType::getCharset)
                .orElse(UTF_8);
        var separatorBytes = SEPARATOR_CHAR.getBytes(charSet);
        if (separatorBytes.length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Charset %s doesn't encode separator %s to a single byte and is unsupported".formatted(charSet, SEPARATOR_CHAR));
        }
        byte separator = separatorBytes[0];
        return inputMessage.getBody()
                .flatMapSequential(buf -> this.splitBy(separator, buf))
                .windowUntil(buf -> buf.indexOf(i -> i == separator, 0) == 0)
                // need to join byte buffers before calling to string, UTF8 is multi byte
                .flatMap(DataBufferUtils::join)
                .map(buf -> {
                    var r = buf.toString(charSet);
                    DataBufferUtils.release(buf);
                    return r;
                });
    }

    Flux<DataBuffer> splitBy(Byte separator, DataBuffer buf) {
        if (buf.capacity() <= 0) { // e.g. an empty trailing line should still emit an event
            return Flux.just(buf);
        }
        Flux<DataBuffer> r = Flux.empty();
        int separatorIndex;
        while ((separatorIndex = buf.indexOf(i -> i == separator, 0)) >= 0) {
            r = Flux.concat(r, Flux.just(buf.split(separatorIndex), buf.split(1)));
        }
        return Flux.concat(r, Flux.just(buf)).filter(b -> {
            var filtered = b.capacity() > 0;
            if (!filtered) {
                DataBufferUtils.release(b);
            }
            return filtered;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Code below works, however this is fully synchronous code (probably with just prefetching ability). It uses [Apache Http Components](https://hc.apache.org/).

```
HttpClientBuilder.create().build().use { client ->
    val responseHandler = ResponseHandler { response ->
        response.entity.content.use { content ->
            content.bufferedReader().use { buffered ->
                // create class, which can process each line. 
                val processor = StreamedLinesProcessor<TResult>()

                do {
                    val nextLine = buffered.readLine()
                    val needContinue = processor.processNextLine(nextLine)
                } while (needContinue)
                processor.getResult()
            }
        }
    }

    client.execute(HttpGet(url.toString()), responseHandler)
}
```